# gulp-sass generates no outputs

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm trying to use gulp to compile sass to css use the gulp-sass library [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass). But the sass compile task doesn't generate any thing and no error logs are thrown. I already get sass installed through `npm install -g sass`

Here is the project set up I have.

Gulp file content:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/index.scss').pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Sass Content:

```
xuanyue$ cat src/index.scss
@import './variable';

body{
    background: $color;
  }
xuanyue$ cat src/variable.scss
$color: #fff
```

Usage:

```
xuanyue$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── css
├── gulpfile.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── index.scss
    └── variable.scss

2 directories, 5 files
xuanyue$ gulp sass
[17:31:04] Using gulpfile ~/Downloads/test-gulp/gulpfile.js
[17:31:04] Starting 'sass'...
[17:31:04] Finished 'sass' after 8.72 ms
LM-CHD-21016754:test-gulp jinxwu$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── css
├── gulpfile.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── index.scss
    └── variable.scss

2 directories, 5 files
```

package.json

```
xuanyue$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "test-gulp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "natives": "git+https://github.com/addaleax/natives.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add `.on('error', sass.errorLog)` after the sass pipe: `.pipe(sass())` to see if it shows any output? Your code seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a semi colon after the variable definition in your `variables.scss` file

```
$color: #fff;
```

Probably the compiler is throwing an error and the file is not getting compiled.